# IReports, gerar número variável de subrelatorios

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

estou utilizando o Jasper para geração de relatórios, utilizo o IReport para construir os Layouts .Possuo um relatório principal que possui um sub relatório (o motivo do meu problema), o meu relatório principal recebe uma lista de objetos, preciso gerar um subrelatorio para cada item desta lista e popular este subRelatorio com o respectivo item da lista. Alguém sabe como fazer isso, é possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar um table no seu relatório principal.

Algo como:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="ItemDataset" uuid="d3e1e03a-2c83-4436-9e50-79518bc3d337">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ItemDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="130" uuid="dca8961f-ce2d-47ac-879c-b15847d170a9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0))]]></printWhenExpression>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="31" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="31" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#3C8DCB" uuid="f60d1675-6fb6-4569-93ca-de32b3a8e861"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Serif" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Descrição]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f1de366a-b36f-4200-9b1e-7a0009be5373"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="140" uuid="980fffb5-1088-47a6-b00f-b5d08b7093c9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="31" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="31" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#3C8DCB" uuid="16679b95-2e6e-4ca1-b8b6-dd7b74267c56"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Serif" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Valor]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="341e7faf-9680-4941-a9a4-ac78b8f4aae0"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{valor}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
```

e no Java você envia os dados da lista que quer que seja uma  tabela de resultados.

Comment: Vou tentar desta forma.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado. Um forte abraço.